# blur image in z-index on hover

Tags: html, css, transition

I'm trying to make css animation on hover over 3 images stacked on top of each other. After hover image is meant to blur.

Here's my code

html:

```
<img class="leaves" src="leaves_01.png"/><img  class="flower" src="purple_orchid02.png"/><img  class="bird" src="bird_01.png"/>
```

css:

```
img:hover {
    -webkit-filter: blur(4px); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    filter: blur(4px);
}
.leaves{z-index:1;
position:absolute;}
.flower{
    z-index: 999; 
    position:absolute;
}
.bird{
    z-index: 1000;
    position:absolute;
}
```

I managed to get blur over layer bird but not the rest.
How to get the blur over each layer separately but when they're stacked on top of each other?

Any suggestions more than welcome. 
Kind regards, Neko

Comment: You can see example on link below

Comment: http://www.ewelinawoloszyn.com/orchids/blur_01.html

Comment: So do you want all three layers to blur at the same time? Or separately?

Comment: separately that's why I created 3 pngs

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your birds image width covers the other images entirely so when you try to hover over those you are actually hovering over the bird image. you need save your top two png files with no canvas so that they don't interfere with the images below.

Comment: The files I've prepared are pngs with no canvas as far as I know. I tried to add some css : background:none; or background:transparent; but it didn't work either. Any more sggestions?

Comment: just crop the top images so that are no bigger than they need to be - you will need to split the birds and flowers into to separate images. You can then position everything with CSS. If you want all birds to blur when one is hovered over you just need to make sure you give them all the birds class and the same for the flowers.

Answer (score 0):

All of your images cover the entire page so only one of them can ever receive the hover event. Your z-index is irrelevant in this scenario because the three images can't layer and still be accessible when they are all the same size.

You'll need to edit each image to just be the size of the actual content and then adjust your layering based on the size of each image. For example, the bird should be an image of just one bird that is added 3 times with each positioned individually. Then, that can be given the highest z-index so that any images below it will still be accessible.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the hover to apply to all images - use a wrapper e.g. a `div`

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="leaves" src="leaves_01.png"/>
  <img class="flower" src="purple_orchid02.png"/>
  <img class="bird" src="bird_01.png"/>
</div>
```

Now add the :hover to your wrapper

```
.wrapper:hover { -webkit-filter: blur(4px); filter: blur(4px); }
```

If you want to handle each image by itself you can do

```
.wrapper:hover .leaves { ... } 
.wrapper:hover .flower { ... }
.wrapper:hover .bird   { ... }
```